# VBA use variable in place of property

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to create a Sub to populate a ListBox based upon the veriable handed into the sub when it's called upon. something like this:

```
Sub RefreshItemList(sSheet As String, sItem As String, sListBox As String)
 Dim ws As Worksheet
   Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(sSheet)
 Dim x As String
   x = "a"
 Dim Row_Index As Long
   Row_Index = 1
 Dim List_Index As Integer
   List_Index = 0

   sListBox.Clear

   Do Until x = ""
      x = ws.Cells(Row_Index, 2).Value2
      If x = Item Then
         sListBox.AddItem (ws.Range("A" & Row_Index))
         sListBox.List(List_Index, 1) = ws.Range("C" & Row_Index)
         sListBox.List(List_Index, 2) = ws.Range("D" & Row_Index)
         sListBox.List(List_Index, 3) = ws.Range("E" & Row_Index)
         sListBox.List(List_Index, 4) = Round(ws.Range("N" & Row_Index), 3)

         List_Index = List_Index + 1

      End If

     Row_Index = Row_Index + 1
   Loop 

End Sub
```

Comment: So what is not happening, you told us what you are trying to do but not what is actually happening and what the issue you are having is.

Comment: You're certainly getting the "Object Required" error. `sListBox` is a String, not an object.   Is this ListBox on a UserForm, or is it on the worksheet?

Comment: I get a msgbox that states invalid qualifier.  when i debug it highlights the first sListBox.

Comment: Yes, because a string doesn't have any properties or methods like `.List`.  You can do `Me.Controls(sListBox`).AddItem...`  if this code is called in the UserForm's module, etc., but I have better solution.

Comment: `Item` is also an undeclared variable, possibly a typo that should be `sItem`.  Using `Option Explicit` will help you avoid these errors in the future.

Comment: Now I am waiting for you to provide more detaila bout what you *expect* to happen. If possible, provide examples of the input, and the expected output. Do **not** put this in the comments, please revise your original question with the additional informations.

Comment: Yes, Item was a typo.  Me.Controls() did exactly what i wanted it to.

Answer (score 0):

This should take care of it, and has cleaned up the code. Instead of using clumsy `Do` loop until value is null string, just define a range object and then iterate over the range object's Cells.  Using a more object-oriented approach also means we can get rid of the unnecessary variables like `x`, `row_index` and `list_index`:

Put this all in the UserForm's module:

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

    'Example of populating this during the form's initialize event
    Call RefreshItemList("Sheet3", "1", "ListBox1")

End Sub

Sub RefreshItemList(sSheet As String, sItem As String, sListBox As String)
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim rng As Range    'Source range for the listbox control
Dim r As Range      'use thisto iterate over the "rng" Range
Dim lstBox As MSForms.ListBox

'Assign your worksheet
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(sSheet)
'Assign your range, modify as needed
Set rng = ws.Range("A2", ws.Range("A1").End(xlDown))

'Exit sub if the first value is empty
If rng.Cells(1).Value = "" Then Exit Sub

'Get a handle on your ListBox control
Set lstBox = Me.Controls(sListBox)

With lstBox
    .Clear
    .ColumnCount = 5  'Ensure enough columns exist in the listbox
    .ColumnWidths = "20;20;20;20;20"  'Or, you can do this in the Designer. Modify as needed.
    For Each r In rng.Cells
        If r.Value2 = sItem Then
           .AddItem r(1, 1).Value                    'Column A
           .List(.ListCount - 1, 1) = r(1, 3).Value  'Column C
           .List(.ListCount - 1, 2) = r(1, 4).Value  'Column D
           .List(.ListCount - 1, 3) = r(1, 5).Value  'Column E
           '.List(.ListCount - 1, 4) = r(1, 2).Value 'Column B  -- I used this for testing only
           .List(.ListCount - 1, 4) = r(1, 12).Value 'Column N
        End If
    Next
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: I have not been able to get back to this project this week.  I'll look this code over some more next week and try to implement it.  I am a complete noob to VB and Structured text in general so I may have some questions pertaining to the changes you made, but I certainly appreciate your time.